# Required_if laravel with multiple value

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, controller

I have a dropdown menu like this:

```
<select name="selection">
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="stext">
```

I want the following in laravel:

```
public static myfunction(){
   $input = \Input::only('selection','stext');
   $rule = array(
      'selection' => 'required',
      'stext' => 'required_if:selection,2,3',
   );
   $validate = \Validator::make($input,$rule);
}
```

But if I select option 1, `stext` is still required. Why?
How can I fix it?

Comment: you codes is true, check all codes.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**EDIT:**
As pointed out by **LePhleg answer**, there is a nicest syntax for this validation:

```
$rule = array(
  'selection' => 'required',
  'stext' => 'required_if:selection,2,3,
);
```

**Old answer below:**

I think that the require_if validation accept only one value per time.
Try to change your validation code as below:

```
$rule = array(
  'selection' => 'required',
  'stext' => 'required_if:selection,2|required_if:selection,3',
);
```

EDIT:
Check LePhleg answer, is more cleaner.
At the time of the answer that was not possible, just check the question, he was using the same method but not worked.

Comment: Nope. See @LePhleg answer. Way cleaner and proper.

Comment: Since when is the cleaner syntax possible? As far as I can see, it is possible since at least Laravel 4.2: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-required-if

Answer (score 77):

You just have to pass all the values as parameters separated by comma:

```
$rules = array(
      'selection' => 'required',
      'stext'     => 'required_if:selection,2,3'
);
```

Comment: The same can be used for `required_unless`.

Answer (score 5):

try this one

if single match value then used like that

```
'stext'     => 'required_if:selection,2'
```

if you have multiple value then used like that **(separated by comma)**

```
'stext'     => 'required_if:selection,2,3'
```

for more information see documentation [required_if](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-required-if)

Answer (score 1):

You can go ahead with sometimes validation for laravel. you can define a custom closure as in the below example

```
public static myfunction(){
   $input = \Input::only('selection','stext');
   $rule = array(
      'selection' => 'required'
   );
   $validate = \Validator::make($input,$rule);
$validator->sometimes('stext', 'required', function($input){
    return (($input->selection == 1) || ($input->selection == 2));
});
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer sir. but i want to make it so simple i can. because im not expert in laravel. thanks again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the Rule class to override the default behavior.
This should work in case of multiple values:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
..................    
'stext' => Rule::requiredIf(function ()  {
                return in_array(request()->selection,[2,3]);
            }),
```