# Multiple "required_if" on different fields within a Laravel Validator's rule

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm creating some rules for my post fields but I need to add 2 "required_if" from *different* fields within one rule, like if it was a "AND" or a "&&" but from different fields.

```
$validator = $this->validate([
    'form_country'          => 'required|array|min:1',
    'form_country.*'        => 'required|numeric',
    'form_tipo'             => 'required|array|min:1',
    'form_tipo.*'           => 'required|numeric|max:10', ,
    'form_fecha_iti_back'   => 'required|array|min:1',
    //so if the actual form_country is 1 AND the actual form_tipo is 3 or 5
    'form_fecha_iti_back.*' => 'required_if:form_country.*,1|required_if:form_tipo.*,3,5',
]);
```

(It is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274940/required-if-laravel-with-multiple-value)).

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using 5.5 version

Comment: You need to check the validation documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-required-without-all) and see options like `required_with:foo,bar,...`

Comment: Hi UlyssesMarx I already tried with those ones and still the same results

Comment: Just so I make sure I understand your question, if the `form_country` array contains `1` and *(not or)* the `form_tipo` array contains `3` or `5` then `form_fecha_iti_back` requires a value?

Comment: yeap, That is right!

Comment: Since you have `required` for `form_fecha_iti_back` it's always going to require a value, however, this will allow the value to be null. Do you want to allow null values (`[null]`) unless it the `required_if` rules pass or do want it so that null values never pass?

Comment: yes, it'll have null values if it does not meet the conditions

Comment: I was thinking about a custom validation like ---$validator->sometimes('form_fecha_iti_back', 'required', function($request) { return ($request->form_country == 1 && in_array($request->form_tipo, [3, 5])) });--- but I don't know to achieve it since it depends on the current array position

Comment: `in_array(1, $input->get('form_country', [])) && count(array_intersect($input->get('form_tipo', []), [3, 5])) >= 1;`

Comment: I didn't quite understand it, is it possible that you explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the laracasts' user https://laracasts.com/@Cronix I managed to find the solution, and hope that it can help to many other users as it helped me.

```
//so first I create all the common rules within $rules    
$rules = [
    'form_gender' => 'required|array|min:1',
    'form_gender.*' => 'required|string|min:4|max:6',
    // others
];
//then get the requests from the needed fields
$fecha_back = request('form_fecha_iti_back');
$formCountry = request("form_country");
$form_tipo_apoyo = request("form_tipo_apoyo");

//now let's valid if we have any value and produce the custom rules according to the conditions. 
if($fecha_back){
  foreach ($fecha_back as $id => $fecha) {
       if($formCountry[$id] == 1 && $form_tipo_apoyo[$id] == 3 || $form_tipo_apoyo[$id] == 5){
          $rules["form_fecha_iti_back.".$id.""] = "required|date|after:form_fecha_iti_depart.*".$id."";
       } else{
          $rules["form_fecha_iti_back.".$id.""] = "nullable|date|after:form_fecha_iti_depart.".$id."";
       }  
  }
}
//finally we got to validate all the rules
$validator = $this->validate($rules);
```