# I want to check multiple conditions on required_if

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I want to check multiple conditions on `required_if`

```
'minimum_purchase' => 'required_if:is_minimum_purchase,1|integer|min:1|greater_than_field:amount',
```

I want to check all these conditions if my `required_if` matches.

How can i achieve this? any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274940/required-if-laravel-with-multiple-value

Comment: @namelivia i want to check all mentioned conditions integer, min.. only when required_if matches but it fires whether my required_if matches or not