# not_required_when validator in AdonisJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, adonis.js

I know there is a way to extend the `validator` to create own validation rule. But I don't know how to do for my requirements. 
Maybe my objective can be achieved with any existing validation rule

**My scenario:**

I have three roles; say `role_id=1, role_id=2, role_id=2`

I have one `basic registration` rule for all roles and another rule object for their specific fields. I need to make a single rule object for all with conditions, so that I may not validate every rule separately in one request (in a generic function for registration for all roles).
here is my approach;

```
basic_registration : {
        display_picture: 'required',
        first_name: 'required',
        last_name: 'required',
        role_id: 'required',  
        phone_number: 'required|max:15', 
        email: 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        address: 'required',
        state: 'required',
        city: 'required',
        zip_code: 'required',  
        password: 'required',
        password_confirmation: 'required_if:password|same:password',
    },
role1_specific_registration_rules : {
        specific_type_id: 'required',
        other_picture: 'required'
},

role2_specific_registration_rules : {
        discount_code: 'required',
        notification: 'required',
},
role3_specific_registration_rules : {
        vehicle_id: 'required',
        make: 'required',
},
```

then I am calling validation every time for every rule, is there a way to use

```
email: 'not_required_when:role_id,1' // not required when role_id is 1
email: 'not_required_when:role_id,2' // not required when role_id is 2
email: 'not_required_when:role_id,1,3' // not required when role_id is 1 and 3
```

or any approach to use (which seems to be proper)

> update

```
email: 'required_when:role_id,1' // working fine with one value 

email: 'required_when:role_id,1,2' // required when role_id is 1 **or** 2--this is only validating first value
```

or something nested like

```
email: 'required_when:role_id:in:1,2' // nested indicative use
```

or as in Laravel `required_if` accepts array values as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40909156/6594294)

```
email: 'required_if:role_id,1,2' // as in laravel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you use two times **required_when**
like this

```
email: 'required_when:role_id,1|required_when:role_id,2',
```

required email is role_id =1 or role_id=2
this is work in my case

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
required_when as mentioned in the link here
 [indicative required_when](https://indicative-v5.adonisjs.com/docs/requiredwhen)
or you can simply add a custom method in hooks.js which accepts arguments
simply call this function from your validator class

here is simple example of conditional required

```js
const conditionalNotRequired = async (data, field, message, args, get) => {
    if (field == "x" ){
      if((data["type"] == "x" && data["y"] != undefined)       {
        throw message 
      }
      else{
        return
      }
    } 
}
```

Comment: `required_when` is not validating second parameter. It is just validating first value and letting go other

Comment: In that case please try creating a custom validator